# To sort a specific column in a DataFrame in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In SparkR I have a DataFrame `data`. It contains `time`, `game` and `id`.

```
head(data)
```

then gives ID = 1 4 1 1 215 985 ..., `game` = 1 5 1 10 and time 2012-2-1, 2013-9-9, ...
Now `game` contains a gametype which is numbers from 1 to 10.

For a given gametype I want to find the minimum time, meaning the first time this game has been played. For gametype 1 I do this

```
data1 <- filter(data, data$game == 1)
```

This new data contains all data for gametype 1. To find the minimum time I do this

```
g <- groupBy(data1, game$time)
first(arrange(g, desc(g$time)))
```

but this can't run in sparkR. It says "object of type S4 is not subsettable".

Game 1 has been played 2012-01-02, 2013-05-04, 2011-01-04,... I would like to find the minimum-time.

Comment: Why do you group by time in the first place? Could you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: I have give an example. I groupBy time since I want to use agg-function to it.

Comment: You don't need `groupBy` to use aggregation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a minimum `time` sorting a whole data set doesn't make sense. You can simply use `min`:

```
agg(df, min(df$time))
```

or for each type of game:

```
groupBy(df, df$game) %>% agg(min(df$time))
```

Answer (score 1):

By typing

```
arrange(game, game$time)
```

I get all of the `time` sorted. By taking `first` function I get the first entry. If I want the last entry I simply type this

```
first(arrange(game, desc(game$time)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify because this is something I keep running into: the error you were getting is probably because you also imported dplyr into your environment. If you would have used `SparkR::first(SparkR::arrange(g, SparkR::desc(g$time)))` things would probably have been fine (although obviously the query could've been more efficient).